# acrofields not printing with multipage document - itextsharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

we are trying to print / create a multi page pdf from a single template pdf containing editable acrofields. The code seemed to work find when using for a simple single page . However when trying to do for multi page, it doesnt seems to be showing values when the multipage pdf is printed.

the code for this is as follows

```
   public ActionResult InsertUpdateFoodCourtMultiple(string FoodCourt, int EmployeeId, string EmployeeNo, DateTime FromDate, DateTime ToDate)
    {
        iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

        String fileName = "";
        fileName = "FoodToken.pdf";
        string filePath = "~/Content/Files/" + fileName;
        byte[] result;

        //create newFileStream object which will be disposed at the end
        using (MemoryStream newFileStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            // step 2: we create a writer that listens to the document
            PdfCopy writer = new PdfCopy(document, newFileStream);

            // step 3: we open the document
            document.Open();

            while (FromDate <= ToDate)
            {

            var reader = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath(filePath));

            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
            var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);

            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("TxtSerial", EmployeeId.ToString());
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("TxtEmployeeId", EmployeeNo);
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("TxtDate", FromDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"));
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("TxtIssuedBy", SessionHelper.GetLoggedInUser().FirstName + " " + SessionHelper.GetLoggedInUser().LastName);
            stamper.AcroFields.SetField("TxtMeal", " - " + FoodCourt);
            stamper.FormFlattening = true;



                // step 4: we add content
                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                    writer.AddPage(page);
                }
                stamper.Close();
            //    writer.AddDocument(reader);
                reader.Close();

                // step 5: we close the document and writer

                //reader = new PdfReader(output);

                //writer.AddDocument(reader);
                //reader.Close();
                FromDate = FromDate.AddDays(1);

            }
            result = newFileStream.ToArray();

            writer.Close();
        }//disposes the newFileStream object

        document.Close();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        return File(result, "application/pdf");


    }
```

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I see two major errors:

#### Copying the unchanged original instead of the filled in copy

In your `while` loop you add the document for the current `FromDate` to the `PdfCopy`:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
    writer.AddPage(page);
}
```

The mistake is, though, that you add the pages from the `reader` containing the *original* "FoodToken.pdf", *not the filled-in* version created in the `stamper`. You actually ignore the result of the `stamper` completely.

Your code in comments shows that you probably once had tried code which attempted to add the filled-in version to the `PdfCopy` instance:

```
//reader = new PdfReader(output);

//writer.AddDocument(reader);
//reader.Close();
```

This is the code you should try to get working. (If your problem with that code was that the `output` already was closed, consider telling the `stamper` not to close the result stream or alternatively simply retrieve its bytes.)

#### Using an unfinished result

You retrieve the contents of the `MemoryStream` the `PdfCopy` writes to before you close the latter and so tell it to finalize its output:

```
result = newFileStream.ToArray();

writer.Close();
```

This causes the `result` to be an incomplete PDF.

Thus, try it the other way around. (If you then run into a problem that the `newFileStream` is closed, consider telling the `writer` not to close the result stream.)

Another thing you shouldn't do is close the `document` after disposing the `MemoryStream` its output is directed to. Here you might be lucky because you closed the `writer` before making `document.Close()` a NOP; in general, though,such a `Close` call is likely to cause some exception.